# How to decrease ubuntu disk space and increase windows' on a dual boot win10/ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 15.04, windows-10

I have Ubuntu 15.04 26G in the /
4G in Swap
and 70 in /home
and i have win10 on a dual boot taking 20G
all on a 120G hard drive 
now i need more space on the win10 partition let's say 20G more and i need to take it from the 70G /home without the risk of losing any data

Answer (score 0):

You can use nice and simple GUI for the partition manager. `sudo apt-get install gparted`. And than do whatever you want with your partitions.